# fluentD, how to use variable at <match>

Tags: fluentd

elasticsearch index Can not use names like this?

```
data: {"key1": "val1"}
```

fluentD conf:

```
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  host localhost
  port 9200
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix ${key1}
  time_key @timestamp
  include_timestamp true
</ match>
```

Error:

```
[warn]: #0 chunk key placeholder '' not replaced. template:${key1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must set chunk_keys.

```
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  # snip
  <buffer tag,key1>
    logstash_prefix ${key1}
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Comment: it's not work.. i got error.
`[warn]: parameter 'logstash_format' in <buffer tag,msname>
  logstash_format 
  logstash_prefix ${msname}
</buffer> is not used.`

Comment: I want to create an index like "mykey1-2019.01.01"

Comment: ${msname} is key1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can specify a custom index, like this:

```sh
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  index_name whatever.${key1}
  <buffer tag, key1>
    logstash_prefix ${key1}
  </buffer>
</match>
```